# query 2 wordpress database tables at once

Tags: wordpress

I have the following query which i am running:

```
$query = "SELECT post_title, ID, post_date_gmt, post_author
        FROM wp_posts 
            WHERE post_type='course-manager' 
        AND post_status='publish' 
        AND SUBSTRING(post_date_gmt,1,4) = '$this->yearGet'
        AND SUBSTRING(post_date_gmt,6,2) = '$this->monthGet'
        AND post_author = '$userid'
        ORDER BY post_title"; 
        $query_result = mysql_query ($query);
        while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($query_result))
        {
```

currently this is querying just the wordpress posts table. i would like to also query data from the wordpress postmeta table, an example would be like this where i have added the "AND course_date which is within the postmeta table:

```
 $query = "SELECT post_title, ID, post_date_gmt, post_author
        FROM wp_posts 
            WHERE post_type='course-manager' 
        AND post_status='publish' 
        AND SUBSTRING(post_date_gmt,1,4) = '$this->yearGet'
        AND SUBSTRING(post_date_gmt,6,2) = '$this->monthGet'
        AND post_author = '$userid'
            AND course_date = '$this->yearGet'
        ORDER BY post_title"; 
        $query_result = mysql_query ($query);
        while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($query_result))
        {
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to query a combined set of data whose source is from more than one table, you need to do a join. Basically, you need to make the connection between the 2 tables, in the post and postmeta case, that connection would be the post id. So the query should look like this:

```
SELECT a.something, b.anotherthing
FROM wp_posts AS a JOIN wp_postmeta AS b
ON a.ID = b.post_id
//followed by all of your where clause...
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, when i add this in, i get the following error: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/sjm/public_html/education/wp-content/themes/1024px/inc/diaryClass.php on line 100